# Azure Application Insights does not report for .NET Framework application due some failures

Tags: azure-application-insights

I installed the following ApplicationInsights nuget packages:

[image]
[image]

After a while, in trace logs, I got a lot of failures

```
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=2.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not implement 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.ITelemetryInitializer'. Type loading was skipped. Monitoring will continue.
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel' will not be create. Error: 'Constructor on type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor' not found.'. Monitoring will continue if you set InstrumentationKey programmatically.
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector, Version=2.11.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not implement 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.ITelemetryInitializer'. Type loading was skipped. Monitoring will continue.
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureWebAppRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer, Version=2.11.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not implement 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.ITelemetryInitializer'. Type loading was skipped. Monitoring will continue.
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.BuildInfoConfigComponentVersionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer, Version=2.11.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not implement 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.ITelemetryInitializer'. Type loading was skipped. Monitoring will continue.
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector' will not be create. Error: 'Constructor on type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor' not found.'. Monitoring will continue if you set InstrumentationKey programmatically.
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer, Version=2.11.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not implement 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.ITelemetryInitializer'. Type loading was skipped. Monitoring will continue.
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.PostSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.Web' was not found. Type loading was skipped. Monitoring will continue.
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel' will not be create. Error: 'Constructor on type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor' not found.'. Monitoring will continue if you set InstrumentationKey programmatically.
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights' will not be create. Error: 'Constructor on type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor' not found.'. Monitoring will continue if you set InstrumentationKey programmatically.
```

The applicationinsights config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
    <InstrumentationKey>AAAAAXXXXXX</InstrumentationKey>
    <TelemetryInitializers>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.BuildInfoConfigComponentVersionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.WebTestTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SyntheticUserAgentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web">        
            <Filters>search|spider|crawl|Bot|Monitor|AlwaysOn</Filters>
        </Add>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AzureAppServiceRoleNameFromHostNameHeaderInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.UserTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AuthenticatedUserIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AccountIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SessionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </TelemetryInitializers>
    <TelemetryModules>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector">
            <ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
                <Add>core.windows.net</Add>
                <Add>core.chinacloudapi.cn</Add>
                <Add>core.cloudapi.de</Add>
                <Add>core.usgovcloudapi.net</Add>
            </ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
            <IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities>
                <Add>Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs</Add>
                <Add>Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus</Add>
            </IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities>
        </Add>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
        </Add>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AppServicesHeartbeatTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureInstanceMetadataTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer">
        </Add>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.DeveloperModeWithDebuggerAttachedTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnobservedExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer">
        </Add>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web">
            <Handlers>
                <Add>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.RequestDataHttpHandler</Add>
                <Add>System.Web.StaticFileHandler</Add>
                <Add>System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader</Add>
                <Add>System.Web.Optimization.BundleHandler</Add>
                <Add>System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory</Add>
                <Add>System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler</Add>
                <Add>System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryRequestHandler</Add>
                <Add>System.Web.HttpDebugHandler</Add>
            </Handlers>
        </Add>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AspNetDiagnosticTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </TelemetryModules>
    <ApplicationIdProvider Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.ApplicationId.ApplicationInsightsApplicationIdProvider, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights"/>
    <TelemetrySinks>
        <Add Name="default">
            <TelemetryProcessors>
                <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector"/>
                <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights"/>
                <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
                    <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
                    <ExcludedTypes>Event</ExcludedTypes>
                </Add>
                <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
                    <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
                    <IncludedTypes>Event</IncludedTypes>
                </Add>
            </TelemetryProcessors>
            <TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel"/>
        </Add>
    </TelemetrySinks>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

How to fix them ?

Comment: Is this a sudden error? which version of .NET framework are you using? and also let us know the configuration code if you have.

Comment: I posted configuration file. I use net framework 4.6.1